# Why does the settings application start up after I click on the Opera icon in my panel?

Tags: windows, windows-10, opera

When I click the Opera icon on my panel, Opera opens and `settings` also starts up, Why is this?
I've checked my Opera settings and I can't find which setting triggers this.
How do I stop this from happening?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because Opera is not updating the Preferences file for some reason. See if this helps.

Close all instances of Opera.

Open this folder:

> C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable

Rename the file `Preferences` to `Preferences.OLD`

Start Opera.

When it asks: `"Would you like to set Opera as your default browser?"`, enable `"Don't ask again"` checkbox and click `No`.

([via MS Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/settings-screen-with-choose-default-applications/8b4ad18e-288c-4a24-993b-0f796af7d4df))

Comment: Thank you! You rock! It works just as expected, thanks again this really made my day.

Comment: @Mango: YW. I think the latest update of Opera fixes this.. I can no longer repro the problem after the update.